# Trying to read a docx file using FastAPI and python-docx library: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek' error

Tags: python, python-docx, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI (not async) and python-docx library, trying to read a docx file.
I'm getting an error while trying to read the docx file.

My code -

```
@app.post('/translate_docx', response_class=PlainTextResponse)
def translateDocx(docFile: UploadFile = File(...), fileExtension: str = Form(...)):
 
    if(fileExtension == 'docx'):
        raw_txt = readDocx(docFile.file.read())

    return raw_txt


def readDocx(file):
    doc = Document(file)
    txt = ""
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        txt = txt + para.text
    return txt
```

**Logs:**

```
File "/translateProject/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/opc/pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_file
    phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
  File "/translateProject/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx/opc/phys_pkg.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'r')
    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1258, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1321, in _RealGetContents
    endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 259, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
    
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

What is wrong in my code ? Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `.read()` the file that is given to `Document()`. Just give it the filename or you can give it an open file that has it's cursor set on offset 0. If the "file" you have is already a bytes object then you can use an `io.BytesIO` "in-memory" file to give to `Document()`.

The `docx_file` parameter in `Document(docx_file)` can be a `str` file path or can be a file-like object (an open file created with `open(...)` or an in-memory file created with `io.BytesIO`), but it cannot be a `bytes` object (what is returned by `file.read()`).

Comment: I tried your solution for reading a docx file using FastAPI, but I get an AttributeError: `'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'seekable'`. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I found a solution. This problem is solved by extracting the binary of UploadFile using await and passing it to the document using bytesio (https://coder-question.com/cq-blog/607280). The code is `doc = Document(BytesIO(await file.read()))`

Answer (score 1):

> UploadFile's object has a File property that contains _file which is io.BytesIO

This worked for me. It returns all the content of the document.

```
def endpoint(file : UploadFile = File(...)):

     doc = Document(file.file._file)
```