# FastAPI upload a file and pass it into python-docx's Document

Tags: python, fastapi, python-docx, python-3.11

I want to upload an  `.docx` document using FastAPI's method (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/), and then pass that file (using bytes) into `python-docx`'s Document. I've tried to use @Mazze solution from question ([Trying to read a docx file using FastAPI and python-docx library: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375466/trying-to-read-a-docx-file-using-fastapi-and-python-docx-library-attributeerror/64376098#64376098)) but i got

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not BytesIO
```

Python: 3.11.5
FastAPI: 0.103.2
Python-docx: 0.8.11

```
from docx import Document
from io import BytesIO

from fastapi import UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/upload", responses={HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST: {"model": Error}})
async def upload_document(file: UploadFile) -> dict[str, Any]:
    file_name: str = file.filename
    doc = Document(BytesIO(await file.read()))
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=HTTPStatus.CREATED,
        content={"file_name": file.filename},
    )
```

What I've tried also:

```
doc = Document(BytesIO(await file.read()).read())
# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

and

```
doc = Document(base64.decodebytes(BytesIO(await file.read())))
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not BytesIO
```

Comment: One more try: doc = Document(base64.decodebytes(await file.read()))
Result:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: I also tried that:
doc = Document(BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(await file.read())))
.. and I get:
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `docx.Document()` is `(str | IO[bytes] | None) -> docx.document.Document`.

Note that `bytes` is not one of the options. `io.BytesIO` does however meet the `IO[bytes]` type constraint so I think it's safe to say what you want is:

```py
bytes = ...  # -- however you translate the FastAPI payload into bytes --
document = Document(io.BytesIO(bytes))
```

It's possible you need a `file.seek(0)` step before `file.read()` since if it's just finished writing it would be pointing to the end of the file and not the beginning.